# Expand/merge partitions on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, dynamic-disk

I have a 1TB SSD which have 250GB C: and a 700GB D: volumn. Now C: is filled up and there is 350GB free on D: and I want to expand C:. 3rd party software is not considered, can I use Windows dynamic drive to get this work?

Should I just convert the SSD to dynamic disk then I can resize the virtual boundary between C: and D: freely?

If so, after the conversion to dynamic disk, can I put this SSD to another computer and boot from C: successfully? Can I install another OS on another disk on the same computer and dual boot? I heard that there may be problems to do this after a conversion.

The risk of try is very high so I want to be highly sure about the steps before action.

**Updated**: As @lx07 said, you can expand/shrink partitions in Windows Disk Manager, I don't know that feature before. The main need of this question is to preserve C: since it takes so much time to setup C:.

For most default case, the layout of the system disk is

```
system reserved|C:|restore partion|extended partition(D: is a logical drive in it)
```

You need to remove the restore parttion to expand C: to D:

(1) backup D:

(2) use admin command line->diskpart->select disk->select the restore partition->delete partion override->exit

(3) In disk manager, delete D:->delete extended partions that contains D:->expand C:

(4) resotre backup to C:

No need for 3rd party software if you concern about malware/cost,etc.

Comment: https://www.minitool.com/partition-manager/

Comment: Why not consider 3rd party software if *Disk Management* will not do it?  Alternatively you could backup contents of **D:**, delete it, extend **C:** and then recreate and restore **D:** contents again. Note "*Dynamic disks have been deprecated from Windows and we don't recommend using them anymore.*" [source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/change-a-dynamic-disk-back-to-a-basic-disk)

Comment: "Dynamic disks have been deprecated from Windows" where did you see that, its not in the link.

Comment: @ lx07 It seems to be deprecated for server, but for client application is there any reason not to use it? Are you sure Disk Management will not do it? Only trust big companies like MS/Google/Intel/NV/AMD/Oracle or open source solution, don't like to let other 3rd party SW to edit my disk in a bare metal way.